# Using external css links in Nextjs 13 Metadata

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

A new feature called Metadata (https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-metadata) came with Nextjs 13. Head.js seems to have been removed with this feature. By using the  tag I have a css file that I need to import. I used to be able to import it like this:

```js
import Head from 'next/head';

export default function Page() { 

return ( 
<> 
 <Head> 
{/* Example Url */}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.2/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css" />
 </Head> 
</> 

)
}
```

But that doesn't work anymore. Can I do this using the new feature Metadata? Otherwise what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can just go on layout.ts and put this tag inside a head tag without using metadata generation, like this:

```
 export default function layout({
    children,
    }: {
      children: React.ReactNode
    }) {
    return (
        <>
          <html lang="en">
          <head>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.2/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css" />
          </head>
            <body>
              {children}
            </body>
          </html>
        </>
      )
```

EDIT: The Nextjs don't recommend load stylesheet on head links and the new metadata don't enable this option but some users was using this approach:
by [huozhi](https://github.com/huozhi)

> You can use ReactDOM.preload to preload the external changes if
> there're required for your page
>
> import React from 'react-dom'
>
> export default function page() {   ReactDOM.preload(
> '/https://cdn.com/bootstrap.min.css',
> { as: 'stylesheet' },   ) }

That you can see here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/46785
And the error before the new metadata says more about this problem:
[no-stylesheets-in-head-component](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-stylesheets-in-head-component)

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. It gives this error (https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error)

Comment: My fault, i think the solution was here: 

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/46785

Answer (score 0):

From this document
[image]
[link](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-metadata#unsupported-metadata)

You can try this way

```
// your page.jsx
import "@/public/assets/styles/imported_style.css"
```

```
// imported_style.css
@import url("replace with your url");
```